# How do couchbase index react to not valid documents for the index and new valid ones?

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

Whenever you have an index on a document with a certain conditional, if the conditional ever stops being true does it deindex automatically the document?

Example:

```
index a on Abucket(field) where field2='value'
```

When I create the index all the documents on Abucket with `field2='value'` will be indexed.

But what happens if a document changes `field2='value2'`. And then, after changing it back to `value1`

How can this work for documents that do not have the `field2` field, I'm guessing those are simply not indexed but then again, if later the field is added, are they automatically indexed?

And also can an index have a complexe where query? similar to  `WHERE ifmissing(field2, ifnull(bla bla bla))='value2'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm guessing those are simply not indexed but then again, if later the
>   field is added, are they automatically indexed?

Yes, we should be correctly handling cases where fields change, even when those fields are referenced in the WHERE clause of indexe.

We also support complex expressions for the WHERE clauses in indexes.

But if this is where you are headed, let me advise some caution. The principal use case for the WHERE clauses in indexes is to restrict indexes to certain types of documents. Typical WHERE clauses for indexes are something like `WHERE type = 'airport'`. If you find yourself doing something more complicated with them, I suggest some caution before proceeding.

Comment: The reason for this is because technically what I want to do is restrict it for certain types of documents with a new field, that may not be defined in old documents, so if it's not present I would get the value with other fields to see if it corresponds for the index.

Comment: The Index condition must be present in the query(expression must exactly match, the index value can be superset). If Index condition has OR/NOT index may not be selected. So Index condition must be simple and straight forward. Also If leading index key MISSING in the document that will not be indexed. You can use IFMISSING() to overcome this if needed.